# TypeScript complains about a variable which represent proper data structure

Tags: typescript

so I have this odd situation I have this interface:

```
export interface FieldConfig {  
    type: 'text' | 'button' | 'tablelist' | 'input' | 'checkbox' | 'radiobutton' | 'select';    
}
```

now if I set a member as the following all is well:

```
this.uiConfigInit = [

{
   type: "select"
}
```

however if I set the following I get an error:

```
const someVar = {
   type: "input"
}

this.uiConfigInit = [
someVar,   
{
   type: "select"
}
```

So TypeScript does not like it when I declare someVar which is of proper format.

I get an error of:

```
Error:(346, 21) TS2322: Type '{ type: string; value: string; label: any; inputType: string; min: number; max: number; step: number; name: string; storePath: string; }' is not assignable to type 'FieldConfig'.
  Types of property 'type' are incompatible.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"text" | "select" | "input" | "button" | "tablelist" | "checkbox" | "radiobutton"'.
```

as a workaround I can add string as in:

```
    type: 'text' | 'button' | 'tablelist' | 'input' | 'checkbox' | 'radiobutton' | string;
```

but would like to avoid adding `string` to typing.
Any ideas?

regards,

Sean

Comment: why don't you use enum for FieldConfig?

Comment: Type 'string' is not assignable to type , or Type string is not assignable to type ? do you have a type where someVar:'string' instead of someVar:string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript uses heuristics when doing type inference.  For this declaration:

```
const someVar = {
    type: "input"
};
```

The type of `someVar` could theoretically be inferred to be all sorts of things.  For example, `unknown`, `object`, `{type: string}`, `{type: "input"}`, `{readonly type: "input"}`, `{readonly type: "input", someOtherProp?: number}` (I could go on all day) are all compatible with that value.  Which one should the compiler choose?  In this case, absent any other contextual information, the compiler chooses `{type: string}`, which is narrow enough to be useful for reading but wide enough to be useful for writing, assuming you ever want to change the value of the `type` property to some other string.

By the time the compiler gets to a line where you want to use `someVar` as a `FieldConfig`, the compiler has completely forgotten about the particular value it's been set with:

```
const someFieldConfig: FieldConfig = someVar; // error!
```

---

So, what can we do?  The best thing to do in cases where inference doesn't do what you want is probably to use a [type annotation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/typescript-in-5-minutes.html#type-annotations) to tell it what you want:

```
const someVar: FieldConfig = {
    type: "input"
}; // okay

const someFieldConfig: FieldConfig = someVar; // okay
```

Here we've told the compiler that `someVar` is supposed to be of type `FieldConfig`.  When it checks the assignment of `{type: "input"}`, it checks it against `FieldConfig` specifically, and sees that it works.  After that, `someVar` is known to be a `FieldConfig` forever, and you're happy.

---

Another way to proceed is to use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to tell the compiler to infer the narrowest type it reasonably can, with the assumption that you will probably not be writing to it:

```
const someVar = {
    type: "input"
} as const;
/* const someVar: {
    readonly type: "input";
} */
const someFieldConfig: FieldConfig = someVar; // okay
```

---

Either of those should work here.  Okay, hope that helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/FAUwHgDg9gTgLgAgJYDs4hgMwIYGMQIBiSIANgCYDCUKmSA5ggN7AJsJwCeEIAXAgHJ0YOAIQAfQQCMArnDg0xkodimkySAM6iJg1BDlLBuABYhcAaylQwRgTGzkkUWfMW6BmsudEBuYAC+wMAo2AC2IJoQeAQAQo7MrOy4NNoImlARAGrYMAgAvInsxRzcfAgARPpyFUlsAf7FAPQAVAgpKGkZ2bn8LCXsXDz82jCo9I3sAQgtTcF17amI3SDEZFQ0dPT8axTUtAwF6ZkgOTC+CE1NCBgwsACEgcGhEVExCACCKChQcNjoiQWHS6JzOOxIe02h0KTAQC2KQ3KVRQBjgtWKDWCxWByxOuw2B22RAhBK2RxWZwuVwQUAs2E4wSCIXCkWi+AQ+20H00XngRWSS2OPTyMPhgzK-GRqPRUwQ2E0i06cEmbFaipBwr6YrYMBAjhopE4pWGlWqaJVCGmsyBgpW+P2W3B6wd0KFp1yVOutPpjKAA)

Answer (score 1):

Declaring `someVar` as a read-only object by using `as const` will keep its `type` property narrowed to `input` and allow you to use it:

```
const someVar = {
   type: "input"
} as const
```

Answer (score 0):

so ended up explicity setting it:

```
const easingId: FieldConfig = {...
```

but thanks for the answer as `as const` learned something new today.